# Is the quote "Nothing is particularly hard if you divide it into small jobs" by Henry Ford?

Tags: quotes

Widely quoted and attributed to Henry Ford (e.g. in the [Civilization](https://forums.civfanatics.com/threads/the-complete-civ5-quotes-list-wip.384371/) game series):

> Nothing is particularly hard if you divide it into small jobs.

Did Ford say this?

(And if not, who first said/wrote the above quote?)

Comment: Sounds like a better question for WikiQuote - oh look, someone asked [11 years ago](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Talk:Henry_Ford#%22Nothing_is_particularly_hard_if_you_divide_it_into_small_jobs%22) and no-one has resolved it.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, but with the word *subdivide* instead of *divide*:

> Nothing is particularly hard if you subdivide it into small jobs.

- [*Henry Ford Still on the Job With Renewed Vigor*](https://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?id=umn.31951d00327393e&seq=203), *Industrial Management*, Vol LXXIV, October 1927, p 195